# How to request data used post method from a simple html page to yii2 applicaion

Tags: yii2

i am building online payment system for my project and i am new to yii2.
I have a simple html with the address http://localhost/ops/onlineStore/home.php with the following simple code

`

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost/ops/frontend/web/index.php?r=site/payment">
   <input type="hidden" value="35" name="price">
   <input type="hidden" value="Breathney Spears Audio CD" name="product_name">
   <input type="hidden" value="someSore" name="Store">
   <button type="submit" name="redirect"><br>Breatheny Spears <br/>Audio CD<br/>35 Afs</button>
</form>
```

`

now i want to get these posted data from my yii2 app please guide me step by step what to do. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your SiteController in PaymentAction:

you can simply get the values:
$_POST['price'];
...

or to use yii2 functions:
$post_arr = Yii::$app->request->post();
$price = $post_arr['price'];
...

Comment: Bad Request (#400)   Unable to verify your data submission.  this is the error occured when i use both methods

Comment: Thank you sir! done it the issue was csrf token i have disabled in in config/main.php and it worked. however this is not the recommended way due to security. you guys can use this link to do it.   http://zero-exception.blogspot.com/2015/01/yii2-using-csrf-token.html

Answer (score 0):

If your form i realetd  to a Yii2 model You can use Yii2 function  load ..

```
    $model = new MyModel();

    $post = $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post();
```

then you can refer to each attribute as

```
    $post->my_attribute;
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html

Comment: Dear!  im new to yii2!  i just explained what i want please guide me how to do it exactly

Comment: i have added  the link for this  .. take a look at controller guide first